# Download JDK onto a remote server

Tags: ubuntu, mirror, java

I want to get the latest JDK onto a server in a remote location.

Downloading the JDK from Sun's website requires jumping through all kinds of hoops until you actually get the file. I'm not sure exactly if they use cookies or my IP address, but simply copying the file URL and trying `wget` on the server doesn't work.

Googling for mirrors of the JDK, I could only find old versions.

Right now I'm left with the option of downloading it into my computer, then uploading it to the server. This feels slow and stupid.

Anyone got a better idea?

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the replies. Just to clarify, as I'm writing this I'm `rsync`ing the 78MB file to my server. It should be done in about an hour, so it's not such a big deal. However, since this is not the first time I'm doing this, I was hoping for a better solution for next time.

**Solution**: What I ended up doing was

```
sudo aptitude install lynx-cur
www-browser http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/
```

From there it's mostly using the arrow and enter keys, and answering "Yes" to a lot of lynx security questions (about cookies and certificates). Thanks to resonator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you jump through the hoops using lynx/links?

Comment: "Alert!: This client does not contain support for HTTPS URLs." I'm going to investigate this direction, though.

Comment: After installing lynx-cur, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly in the amount of time it will take you to wait for responses to this question, it would probably be quicker to download/upload.

Agreed it is a bit absurd, but I've found myself doing this dozens of times for different things.

Answer (score 0):

Note: you could try from some [mirroring site](http://www.gegereka.com/?query=jdk%206u14)
(however, it would require a verification of the integrity of the file, since they are not always *official* mirrors...)

Answer (score 0):

Download it to a machine with a browser and move it over with SCP or rsync?